# Django Tastypie 1-1 related_name

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, tastypie

I am getting too confused with the proper way to use related_name in django tastypie..

Here's my code description..

In models.py

```
class Item:
  #some fields

class ItemAddOn:
  item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

In api.py

```
class ItemResource(ModelResource):
  itemAddOn = fields.ToOneField('api.ItemAddOnResource',
                                'itemAddOn',related_name="item")
  class Meta:
    #General Tasypie Meta code

class ItemAddOnResource(ModelResource):
  item = fields.ToOneField(ItemResource, 'item', related_name='itemAddOn')

  class Meta:
    #General Tasypie Meta code
```

I basically want to create a post for ItemAddOnResource. When I create that post, I want it to be automatically associated with the Item. But with this code, the field in ItemResource stays null even when I create a post for ItemAddOnResource with the specific item id.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the problem, might be helpful to some one else..

Since this is a 1-1 relation, I shouldn't have been using ForeignKey at the first place. And that would fix the issue.

models.py:

```
class Item:
  #some fields

class ItemAddOn:
  item = models.OneToOneField(Item)
```

api.py:

```
class ItemResource(ModelResource):
  itemAddOn = fields.ToOneField('api.ItemAddOnResource',
                                'itemAddOn',related_name="item")
  class Meta:
    #General Tastypie Meta code

class ItemAddOnResource(ModelResource):
  item = fields.ToOneField(ItemResource, 'item', related_name='itemAddOn')

  class Meta:
    #General Tastypie Meta code
```

This would allow posts to happen either way, a post in ItemResource would create a new itemAddOn, and a post in itemAddOn will associate it with the right item.